# How to throw exception if version of vim is less than a desired target? (.vimrc/init.vim)

Tags: vim, neovim

In short, is there a way to say to do this in both neovim/vim:

```
if (neovim.version < 0.4.3)
  throw "Cannot run script."
endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `has("nvim-x.y.z")` which is mentioned both under `:h has()` and `h v:version`:

```
if !has("nvim-0.4.3")
    " some error processing
    throw "Running under " . (has("nvim") ? "old Neovim" : "Vim")
endif
```